# Excel::Writer::XLSX display_units on y-axis

Tags: excel, perl

I have a chart which contains a y-axis with values in the millions.  Instead of listing such large numbers I wanted to use the display_units => 'millions' option.  If I open up excel and select the axis and change the display units to millions it works.  However in the script I'm running I have this coded:

```
$chart->set_y_axis( display_units => 'millions', name => 'Transactions' );
```

But the chart still lists the y_axis in millions.  Am I missing something or could there be a bug in this option?

Comment: It looks like you are doing it right. Check for typos. The only thing I see in the docs that I'm not clear on is _(Applicable to value axes only.)_ at https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart#set_x_axis. The code there looks pretty clean to me. And a typo would just give you an error message as far as I can tell.

Comment: Nope, no error message.  In fact the script creates the proper chart, with the exception of the y-axis displaying the transactions in millions.  The label name 'Transactions' exists as well.

Answer (score 0):

Excel::Writer::XLSX works for me.

In [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/tree/master/t) there is a regression test for displaying units in the millions.

The test is called [chart_display_units06.t](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/blob/master/t/regression/chart_display_units06.t), and it's comparing to [chart_display_units06.xlsx](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/blob/master/t/regression/xlsx_files/chart_display_units06.xlsx).

When I open the Excel file that is included, it shows correctly on my machine, and the test is passing, with this command:

```
prove -lv t/regression/chart_display_units06.t
```

Also changing the y-axis to `$chart->set_y_axis( display_units => 'millions', name => 'Transactions' );` stills show correctly in my Excel.

I think you need to either give the excel file you are creating, or post more code for us to be able to reproduce the error.